# How does Awk's pattern matching for strings works?

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to understand how the range pattern matching work in Awk
Here is the full data that I am practicing with

```
Raw Data
-----------------------------------------
    USSR    8649    275     Asia
    Canada  3852    25      North America
    China   3705    1032    Asia
    USA     3615    237     North America
    Brazil  3286    134     South America
    India   1267    746     Asia
    Mexico  762     78      North America
    France  211     55      Europe
    Japan   144     120     Asia
    Germany 96      61      Europe
    England 94      56      Europe
```

If I write this code

```
$ awk '/Asia/, /Europe/' countries.awk
```

I get

```
USSR    8649    275     Asia
Canada  3852    25      North America
China   3705    1032    Asia
USA     3615    237     North America
Brazil  3286    134     South America
India   1267    746     Asia
Mexico  762     78      North America
France  211     55      Europe
Japan   144     120     Asia
Germany 96      61      Europe
```

It doesn't output England.

And If I write this

```
$ awk '/Europe/, /Asia/' countries.awk
```

I get

```
France  211     55      Europe
Japan   144     120     Asia
Germany 96      61      Europe
England 94      56      Europe
```

What is the behavior here? Why do I not get England on the first one?

Answer (score 1):

`Awk` process input lines one at a time, the syntax you used is *likely* to print lines from the start to the end pattern, represented by country names. When you used

```
awk '/Asia/, /Europe/'
```

The start of pattern `Asia` happens more than once. As you can see from the line numbers below, numbers `3`,`5`,`8` and `11` represent the start of the pattern and the pattern ends at lines `10` and `12`. Observe carefully the sub-ranges of lines between `8-10` and `11-12`. The *last* end pattern `Europe` for the last `Asia` ends at line `12`, that is the reason you are not seeing `England` in the first case.

But when you used

```
awk '/Europe/, /Asia/'
```

The line containing the first start pattern `Europe` starts at line `10` and ends at `11` another two pattern start at `12` and `13` *without* an end pattern `Asia`, so it would obviously print all the lines until `Asia` appears. So you are seeing `England` in the second case.

```
$ cat -n file
 1  Raw Data
 2  -----------------------------------------
 3      USSR    8649    275     Asia
 4      Canada  3852    25      North America
 5      China   3705    1032    Asia
 6      USA     3615    237     North America
 7      Brazil  3286    134     South America
 8      India   1267    746     Asia
 9      Mexico  762     78      North America
10      France  211     55      Europe
11      Japan   144     120     Asia
12      Germany 96      61      Europe
13      England 94      56      Europe
```

Comment: @Adaptron: See [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Never use range expressions as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then need a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when your requirements change. Always use a flag instead:

```
awk '/Asia/{f=1} f{print} /Europe/{f=0}' countries.awk
```

I bet if you started with that you wouldn't even have had to ask this question as the logic is clear and explicit.